# Removing button in swift

Tags: swift

This is an iOS app. In the PostDetailViewController.swift there is Share Button.

How can I remove or make the following shareButton invisible? Would it be a healthy way to turn them into comment lines with "//" ? Thanks in advance.

```
let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.action, target: self, action: #selector(PostDetailViewController.shareButtonTapped))
        var rightItems = [shareButton]
        if (self.params.count > 2) {
            let commentButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.reply, target: self, action: #selector(PostDetailViewController.showDisqusComments))
            rightItems += [commentButton]
        }
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightItems

        nameLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: post.title!)
```

Comment: Your question does not really make sense.

Comment: @Sulthan As I am not good on swift this is the best I can to describe the issue:)) Simply I do not want that button there

Comment: You are mixing "making button invisible" with "commenting code" and that's what does not make sense. Please, explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sulthan Honestly this is the first time I using xcode and swift. I am a web based front end developer. However, this is an iOS app I have purchased from Codecanyon. There is a shareButton on post detail screen. I do not want users to share and reach any content out of the app. So I want to remove this button.

Comment: Then remove the code, don't comment it. "invisible" means that the button is still there but you cannot see it. You don't want to make it invisible, you want to remove it. This is nothing related to Swift or Xcode. Exactly the same solution would be advised for web development.

Comment: @Sulthan I was considering what if I need it in the next version of the app. So commeting the code seemed easier for future revisions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nope, that's what code versioning tools are for (e.g. git). Commented code is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.action, 
     target: self, action: #selector(PostDetailViewController.shareButtonTapped))
var rightItems = [shareButton]
```

To

```
var rightItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
```